# Choosing the direction of a vector

Tags: vectors

First off, thank you for helping.

In the AQA june 2015 C4 exam on vectors they asked to determine the the value of a position vector called C that is on the line "l" along with a known vector A such ABC is a right angle. "B" being also known, the solution to the problem required the scalar product of AB.BC and AB.CB does not yield the desired result.

In the Jan 2013 AQA C4 exam they asked to verify the "acute" angle of ABC and all the vector positions were known but in order to get the correct result the scalar product of AB.CB had to be taken for AB.BC yielded the obtuse angle.

My question is: How should I determine the angle between two vectors starting with three position vectors? Is there a rule to this or do I just guess.

Answer (score 0):

Given two vectors $u$ and $v$, the angle $\theta$ = $\displaystyle \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{u • v}{||u||•||v||}\right)$

Inverse cosine of (dot product over product of magnitudes)